# Not able to get the values from this function

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The fetch works fine, but the "title" array has no values in it after pushing the values from the fetch data.

```
    function getdata(){
    const title = [];
    const body = [];
     const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
      fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
        //  console.log(data)                        /*This works just fine*/
         data.forEach(posts => {
            title.push(posts.title)
            body.push(posts.body)
            })
     })
    //  const onlytentitle = title.slice(0,9);     
    //  return onlytentitle;
        return title;     
}
const titled = getdata();
console.log(titled);
```

Comment: You're returning title before it's been processed by the promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` is an async function and you are returning title from outside the fetch, so your function will return the title before the fetch request complete.

Try this.

```
function getdata() {
  const title = [];
  const body = [];
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(posts => {
        title.push(posts.title);
        body.push(posts.body);
      });
      return title;
    });

}
(async function() {
  const titled = await getdata();
  console.log(titled);
})();
```

**With `async/await`**

```
async function getdata() {
  const title = [];
  const body = [];
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = await response.json();
  data.forEach(posts => {
    title.push(posts.title);
    body.push(posts.body);
  });
  return title;
}
(async function() {
  const titled = await getdata();
  console.log(titled);
})();
```

Comment: Why not refactor the code to use async/await pattern in toto.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have added async/await.

Comment: @Sohail  -  so i need a global variable which holds the values of the "titled"  which is inside the function of the anonymous async call. so can u please tell me how to do that.

Comment: just declare the `titled ` variable ouside the function with `let`. e.g. `let titled;
(async function() {
  titled = await getdata();
  console.log(titled);
})();`

Comment: but when i console log it outside of the function it says "undefined" , but i want that to hold all the values.

Comment: yes, because the titled hold value returned from an async function.